# type_name keyword as a column name in DBT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a column name **type_name** . As Type_name is a keyword in dbt , I could not run my DBT model

```
select 
  type_name as type_name_ 
from {{ source('sn','accounts') }}
```

Could you please help me resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that type_name is an unquoted column name in the source table:

```
select 
  "TYPE_NAME" as type_name_ 
from {{ source('sn','accounts') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I used

```
select 
  accounts.TYPE_NAME as type_name_ 
from {{ source('sn','accounts') }}
```